# What is the topology of a simplicial complex?

Tags: algebraic-topology

I know what a simplicial complex is, but when reading about triangulations on surfaces I found that there must exist a homeomorphism betwen the space underlying the surface and some simplicial complex. So my question is, how is defined the topology of a simplicial complex?

Comment: What definition of simplicial complex do you know?

Answer (score 4):

There is no (to my knowledge) topology directly on the simplicial complex. However, there is a way to canonically get a topological space from a simplicial complex called [geometric realization](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Abstract_simplicial_complex#Geometric_realization). This is what you are looking for.

Comment: This works when the complex is finite.  But an infinite complex in Euclidean space may not have the subspace topology.

Comment: @Timkinsella: What does not work, exactly? The construction I linked is perfectly valid and yields a topological space even when the complex is infinite.

Comment: Yes, you're right.  Sorry about that.  I still think the "coherent with its simplices" definition is simpler and more standard, though.

Comment: @Timkinsella: It's exactly the same thing. Look closely, there is a direct limit involved in the definition of geometric realization.

Comment: Oh I agree they are equivalent.  Sorry I didn't mean to nitpick.  Two perspectives are always better than one :)

Answer (score 2):

Simplicial complexes have the topology coherent with their simplices (which are topologized as homeomorphs of the standard simplices living in Euclidean space).  This means a subset of the complex is closed if and only if its intersection with each simplex is closed.

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Coherent_topology